# Why Int in kotlin is not possible to extend

Tags: kotlin, generics

I don't understand why Int is a final class in kotlin but is a public class in code source [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3tdT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKhTl.png)
Maybe you have the reponse for why

I try to extend the class primitive in kotlin for create little librairy like zod in typescript and squant in scala

Comment: Classes are "not `open`" by default. `Public` isn't about whether you can extend it or not.

Comment: Are you asking about the language design reason or are you asking because you thought "public" means "open"?

Comment: If it's possible, why isn't it open or public that says whether a class is open or not? What is it then?

What about the design system?